# snowflake selective removal of load metadata

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a large table in snowflake(terabytes per month) which gets loaded using an external S3 stage. I have loaded data into it using a wrong COPY command for a month. I know the pattern of the S3 objects thats got loaded and I store them in the table in one  of the column.

Is there anyway for me to selectively remove already loaded metadata for this table. So the table forgets about these specific metadata being already loaded.

Idea is If I can then delete those records using the s3 Objects name and then load back those s3 objects again by fixing my COPY command ?

The other option I have is load these S3 objects into another table and perform an UPSERT.

But I am just checking if there is any option for selective removal of **Loaded Metadata** on Snowflake Table ?

Any answer is welcome . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can alter the metadata.. (which really means I don't feel you can but also have not looked too hard, as I have other options)

You can

```
COPY INTO 
[ FILES = ( '<file_name>' [ , '<file_name>' ] [ , ... ] ) ]
```

and this list the set of files

and use the `FORCE = TRUE` to make it ignore that meta list.

Which might be as hoop jumping as loading into another load, and then merging in. It depends if you are trying have it all auto-magic as part of your "normal process" and thus do all the other normal things.

But that begs the question if you have 100's or 1000's of files, and are relying on the "metadata/file age" to prune the list of files, to just the new's, your COPY INTO will suffer a performance hit of doing this, all the time. One way around this is to use highwater marks of dates, and step into the  now. Which mean you could reset the highwater mark (this is how we handled the task) and our code dynamically loaded blocks in batch, so would normally be working in the "current hour" but if was weeks/months behind (the watermark was reset) it would load month chunks. So the data was not too much for the warehouse (and because we where load balancing many tables)...

Anyways. Those are some other options/thoughts.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. Can you please provide an example for your statement kindly. One way around this is to use highwater marks of dates, and step into the now. Which mean you could reset the highwater mark (this is how we handled the task) and our code dynamically loaded blocks in batch, so would normally be working in the "current hour" but if was weeks/months behind (the watermark was reset) it would load month chunks. So the data was not too much for the warehouse (and because we where load balancing many tables)

Comment: That sentence/paragraph packs a lot of intent, somewhat because its a complex topic. Do you have a part of the paragraph that does not make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks Simon . I was asking about the high water mark and  dynamically load blocks in batch concept ? A small example will do. Thanks in advance.